# ¿Cómo actualizar Obout Grid de Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lo que quiero es que cuando inserte un nuevo elemento a mi base de datos la grid recargue con el nuevo dato.

Estoy usando Obout Grid en Javascript pero no lo consigo.

```
<ClientSideEvents ExposeSender="true" OnClientInsert="refreshGrid2"         OnClientUpdate="refreshGrid2" />
```

Y tengo mi función así:

```
function refreshGrid2() {
    alert(1)
    grdCatalogo.refresh();
}
```

También intenté que cuando le pique el botón de aceptar, o sea cuando suba el registro, se actualice el grid con jQuery, pero nada.

Comment: porque en el titulo mencionas el GridView y depsues mencionas Obout Grid ? no se realiza un evento al servidor cuando insertas un nuevo registro? usas el control UpdatePanel ?

Comment: Perdón por el engañoso titulo, ya lo habia hecho con c# pero me piden que lo haga con js

Comment: Sí, estoy usando el update panel

Comment: ok pero los controles de asp.net mvc no se llevan bien con javascript, tienes que recargar la pagina o sino usar un control que sea compatible con esta forma de trabajar, como ser usando el jQGrid o similar

Comment: si usas el UpdatePanel recuerda incluir dentro del template del UpdatePanel tambien el gridview asi esa seccion se actualiza y si reasignas el DataSource del grid se mostrara el nuevo dato

Comment: Sí, así lo tenia, volvia a asignar el data sourse, y funcionaba, pero ahora me piden que lo haga con js

Comment: entonces no queda otra que cambiar el GridView por un contrl compatible, recomiendo el jQGrid o el DataTable (https://datatables.net/). El GridView no aplica para trabajar integrado a codigo dinamico generado con codigo cliente

Comment: Gracias @LeandroTuttini

Answer (score 1):

En el desarrollo se usaba el `UpdatePanel` pero se necesita trabajar con el `GridView` usando `javascript`

Esto traerá problema con el `viewstate` al alterar el `html` de la tabla que renderiza cuando se utilice `javascript` (o `jquery`).

Aconsejaría cambiar el `GridView` por un control compatible con esta forma de trabajo, recomiendo el [jQGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Trirand.jqGrid/4.5.1) o el [DataTable](https://datatables.net/).

El `GridView` causará muchos problemas cuando se quiera alterar con código `javascript`

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar hacerlo desde Codebehind asignando nuevamente el DataSource del GridView, obviamente de esta manera estaría recargando nuevamente tu página.

¡Mucha Suerte!